# Do not copy swift libraries with Xcode 8?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, build, xcode8

How to **not** automatically embed Swift dynamic libraries in Xcode 8?

I've tried setting `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` to "No" (defaults to "No" anyway) yet it still copies Swift dynamic libraries into the app bundle.

I'm creating a helper application to be embedded in the main application and the latter already has Swift libraries which the former can link to.

Answer (score 0):

Swift may still be copied even for `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` set to NO. You can check if there is some Swift file in your project or any of your dependencies and remove those.

Comment: The question is for **not embedding** Swift libraries for a Swift target.

Comment: In that case I think it is embedded even when setting `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` to NO because it is a standalone target and therefore it would need the libraries to be runnable. You may want to try to create the embedded app as a library/framework. Would that help?

Comment: But would creating the app as a library/framework prevent the app from launching as it's not an executable? Note that a framework's bundle's structure is vastly different than an app bundle.

Comment: That I don't know, sorry.